# Calculate deciles based on subgroup and apply to entire dataset

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset with columns:

```
subgroup: [group1, group2]
distribution: continuous variable
```

I want to calculate deciles based on a subgroup of the dataset:

```
df <- df %>%
  filter(subgroup == "group1") %>%
  mutate(decile = ntile(distribution, 10))
```

then I would like to use the obtained deciles and apply it to the entire dataset (i.e. not just group1).

is there a way to do this?

here's an example dataset

```
df <- matrix(0,ncol=3,nrow=10000)
df[,1] <- 1:10000
df[,2] <- sample(c("group1","group2"),10000,replace=T)
df[,3] <- rnorm(10000)
df <- as.data.frame(df)
colnames(df) <- c("id", "subgroup","value")
```

I select the subgroup `group1` and calculate deciles based on the column `value`

```
df %>% filter(subgroup == 'group1') %>%
 mutate(decile = ntile(value, 10))
```

then I would like to use the obtained deciles, and classify `subgroup=='group2'` based on the deciles obtained from `'group1'`

the desired output would be a 4th column in `df` with a single value between 1 and 10 for each observation. (i.e. the decile classification for each observation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use `cut` to divide the values into decile groups based on "group1".

```
library(dplyr)

df |> 
  mutate(decile = cut(value, 
                      quantile(value[subgroup == "group1"], seq(0, 1, 0.1)),
                      labels = FALSE)
         )
```

Output:

```
     id subgroup        value decile
1     1   group1  0.674098613      8
2     2   group1 -2.881811886      1
3     3   group1 -0.377427063      4
4     4   group1  0.461585185      7
5     5   group1  0.460216469      7
6     6   group1 -1.374041767      1
7     7   group1 -0.945986918      2
8     8   group2  0.472525168      7
9     9   group2  0.418391193      7
10   10   group2  0.746413150      8
11   11   group2  0.175323464      6
12   12   group1  0.879160602      9
13   13   group1  0.469811384      7
14   14   group2  0.639019379      8
15   15   group1 -0.328276877      4
16   16   group1 -0.099512041      5
17   17   group1 -0.714642875      3
18   18   group1 -0.404702209      4
19   19   group1 -2.181077079      1
20   20   group2 -2.298182006      1
```

Data:

```
df$value <- as.numeric(df$value)
```

Comment: is it possible to do the same thing but instead of splitting into deciles based on 1 variable, I split based on 2 variables?

Comment: You could do `value[subgroup %in% c("group1", "group2")]` :)